# How to solve CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long error of maven-protobuf-plugin?

Tags: windows, maven, kotlin, protocol-buffers, protoc

How can one solve this error when building a Maven project that uses protobufs?

```
org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile (default) on project my-module: An error occurred while invoking protoc: Error while executing process.: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

I use maven-protobuf-plugin version 0.6.1, I am running IntelliJ on Windows.

I have tried to

- add `-Didea.dynamic.classpath=true` to the `mvn clean install`
- command add `&quot;dynamic.classpath&quot;: &quot;true&quot;` to `PropertiesComponent` in `workspace.xml` of IntelliJ
- install a newer version of the protoc compiler
- build from terminal outside Intellij
- updating IntelliJ

but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue set the `<useArgumentFile>true</useArgumentFile>` configuration option in the plugin, as mentioned [here](https://www.xolstice.org/protobuf-maven-plugin/usage.html) under

> Dealing with "Command line is too long" errors

It should look like this in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.1</version>
    <configuration>                   
        <useArgumentFile>true</useArgumentFile>
    </configuration>
```

Related GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/xolstice/protobuf-maven-plugin/issues/5).